Search flag by colors
I have that code:
(deftemplate country
    (slot name)
    (multislot flag_colors))

(deffacts countries
    (country (name "United States of America") (flag_colors red white blue))
    (country (name "Belgium") (flag_colors black yellow red))
    (country (name "Poland") (flag_colors white red))
    (country (name "Monaco") (flag_colors white red))
    (country (name "Sweden") (flag_colors yellow blue))
    (country (name "Panama") (flag_colors red white blue))
    (country (name "Jamaica") (flag_colors black yellow green))
    (country (name "Colombia") (flag_colors yellow blue red))
    (country (name "Italy") (flag_colors green white red))
    (country (name "Ireland") (flag_colors green white orange))
    (country (name "Greece") (flag_colors blue white))
    (country (name "Botswana") (flag_colors blue white black)))

(defrule find-countries-with-colors
   ?c <- (country (name ?name) (flag_colors $?colors))
   ?input-colors <- (input-colors $?userColors)
   (test (subsetp $?userColors $?colors))
   =>
   (printout t "Country: " ?name crlf))

(deffunction subsetp (?sublist ?list)
   (if (or (not (listp ?sublist)) (not (listp ?list)))
       then FALSE
       else
       (foreach ?element ?sublist
          (if (not (member ?element ?list))
              then return FALSE))
       return TRUE))

(defrule get-user-input
   (declare (salience 10))
   =>
   (printout t "Enter colors separated by spaces: ")
   (bind ?colors-string (readline))
   (bind ?colors (explode$ ?colors-string))
   (assert (input-colors (create$ ?colors))))

(defrule no-match-found
   (not (find-countries-with-colors))
   =>
   (printout t "No country found with the specified colors." crlf))

(defrule run
   (declare (salience -10))
   =>
   (run))

When I run it, I get the following error:

Defining deftemplate: Country
Defining deffacts: Countries
Defining defrule: find-country-by-colors
[PRNTUTIL2] Syntax Error:  Check appropriate syntax for defrule.
ERROR:
(defrule MAIN::find-country-by-colors
?request <- (request (
Defining deffunction: subsetp
[DFFNXPSR2] Deffunctions are not allowed to replace external functions.
ERROR:
(deffunction MAIN::subsetp
(
Defining deffunction: main
[EXPRNPSR3] Missing function declaration for colors.
ERROR:
(deffunction MAIN::main
()
(printout t "Enter colors separated by spaces: ")
(bind ?user-colors (explode$ (readline)))
(assert (request (colors
FALSE

Please, help me, I have no idea. I'm just learning.
The essence of the program is that it should ask for colors, and then, based on the entered colors, output all the countries whose flags contain all these colors.

A good question title is not about what kind of real-world problem you're trying to model or what the program you're writing is trying to do, but rather focused on describing the specific technical problem you encountered during the process -- that way people with the same technical problem can find your question and learn from its answers, even if they encountered that problem while writing a completely different kind of program for a completely different purpose.

This is the error from your code:
[DFFNXPSR2] Deffunctions are not allowed to replace external functions.

ERROR:
(deffunction MAIN::subsetp
   (

You're getting this error because you're trying to redefine a function that already exists:
         CLIPS (6.4.1 4/8/23)
CLIPS> (subsetp (create$ a d) (create$ a b c d))
TRUE
CLIPS> (subsetp (create$ x) (create$ a b c d))
FALSE
CLIPS> 

